# python json shema return all validation errors

Tags: python, json, validation, jsonschema

I'm trying to validate json using python validictory, but when I get a validation error the validation ends and missing field name is reported, but if there is more than one field missing I only get a message about the first one. I need to know about all the fields that are missing. Is there an function which will return all missing fields?

This script only needs to validate a json document, so answers using other libraries, languages are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call [`.validate()`](http://validictory.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validictory.html#validate) set `fail_fast` property to `False`. That will force `validictory` to return all errors instead of only first one.